# Difficulties one undergo when he is in pretha janma dosha

Tags: puranas, birth

What sort of form does a person attain when in pretha janma dosha? What sort of actions he will do to his family? How does he look like and will he cause difficulties to his family? On the contrary what sort of persons will not be disturbed by the pretha janma dosha?

Comment: what is preda Janma Dosha?

Comment: When a body is entering its preda [dead] form the dosha for that is called as preda janma dosha

Comment: how to confirm if someone is having it ? which scripture talks of it?

Answer (score 1):

Stealing other's wealth, cheating others and taking their belongings take the wind type predha roop and will roam with hungry and thirst. He will cause difficulty to his family members and relatives.He will not allow pithrus to enter the house on ceremony [pithru arrival days]. He will take the havis offered for them.He will cause difficulty to his son by preventing child to him.The persons in the family who is having bad habits will be put to lots of difficulties. Child will born and die likewise it continues, non coopearion in the family,  unable to save the cow, enmity with friends, cannot adhere upavas, preventing good deeds, causing fight all caused by this preda janma. This will surround the family because preda janma dosha is very difficult to rfemove due to stealing of wealth, jewellery and belongings of others.
Source---Garuda Puranam---Punishment 1 is Tamisram for this preda Janma.

Comment: You shouldn't just say Garuda Purana, you should give the specific chapter and/or verses.